# Is "freak-out" an active or a passive experience?

Tags: verbs, intransitive-verbs

The OED defines the verb *freak-out* as meaning:

> 3. to freak out (occas. without out): to undergo an intense emotional experience, to become stimulated, to rave, esp. under the influence of
>      hallucinatory drugs. Also trans., to cause (a person) to be aroused or
>      stimulated in such a way. (Also in more trivial uses.) So
>      freaked-out adj. affected thus.  freaking-out n.

Examples of *freak-out* are given from 1965. They stop in 1970, suggesting that this was perhaps a word of the 60s, though I still hear it being used mostly by Americans, a lot during the recent election campaign.

Typically the OED's examples are in both an active and passive context.

> 1970   It 27 Feb. 11/1   Aage leaps about and shouts at them and
>   freaks them out.
>
> 1970   Nature 23 May 704/1   One question asked the respondents how
>   often they had seen other people ‘freak out’, that is, have intense,
>   transient emotional upsets.

The first of the above is a transitive verb, the second an active intransitive verb.

Sometimes people get *freaked-out*, sometimes they *freak-out*. In a newspaper article I have been reading on people who supported Donald Trump, a 25-year-old man, James Morrison says *I was freaked out about Hillary because there were 33,000 emails...*.So, who or what did the freaking-out? Hillary is an indirect object governed by 'about'.

Now that does not sound quite the same sort of thing someone saying they *freaked-out because of the 33,000 emails...*

So how does the meaning change here between these two uses? Can anyone throw any light on the matter, please?

**Edit. After giving further thought to this and after a helpful dialogue of comments with others, which has better crystallised the issue in my mind, I feel I should re-pose the question. What concerns me is that *freaking-out*, it seems, can be both a self generated experience (*he freaked out*) or something that is inflicted upon one (*it freaked him out*). I cannot for the moment think of any other verbs which behave in quite this way. Can anyone else?**

Comment: re "the first of the above is in the passive, the second an active verb". How so? Both are grammatically active, but the difference is that the first example uses freak out as a transitive verb, and the second as an intransitive.

Comment: I agree with @ArmenԾիրունյան, though I do not know what keyboard I should use to type the second part of your name :)

Comment: @Jason you don't have to type out one's name completely to tag them. Just any unique prefix will do. But if you're wondering, you'd need to use an Armenian keyboard to type that :)

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան Good point. 'I was freaked out* is a transitive use. I will edit this later.?

Comment: "@WS2: No, I was freaked out is indeed passive, but your first example is "... freaks them out". That's transitive.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան I think I have clarified this with my editing.

Comment: 'I was freaked out' with no by-phrase is almost certainly best regarded as an adjectival usage. I was angry / distraught / worried / disturbed.....

Comment: You are conflating the everyday and the grammatical senses of 'passive'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So far as I am aware my edited version makes no reference to the grammatical passive voice. That is why I used the term *passive context*. Are there any comparable intransitive verbs, where the past participle can be used adjectivally to describe the subject? Would it be like "He worried", "he was worried"?

Comment: Since "freak out" is informal, and has no roots in Latin or German or whatever, it is apt to be used in many different ways.

Comment: Even in your edited version, you are conflating the everyday and the grammatical senses of 'active'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That may be so, but if you read my comments to both Josh and Mitch you will see where my real concern lies. It is with the logic of its meaning.

Comment: Questions shouldn't require explanatory comments. / 'Freaked out' may best be regarded as an adjective; as with 'bewildered', 'confused', 'tired [out]', 'exhausted', 'frightened', 'spaced out'... the agent / inanimate cause is backgrounded so far as to be rarely considered. 'X freaked him out' / 'He was freaked out by X' is obviously a different matter.

Comment: That explains *X freaked him out*. But how about *He freaked out*. It seems that *freaking out* can be both self-generated and the result of someone else's action. What do you say to that?

Comment: Just a note on the OED's examples ending in 1970—there is a note on both the entry for *freak, v.* and *freak-out, n.* that they have "not yet been fully updated." The entry for *freak-out* was apparently added in the 1972 supplement, and as far as I can see was not updated in the 1989 edition at all. I would expect to see many later examples once the pertinent entries are revised.

Comment: @WS2 - You need to understand that "freak out" is a prime example of the nature of a living, breathing language.  The term arose spontaneously, not by inheritance from another language or by gradual mutation.  And it was formed in the youth/hippie culture that placed little store (none at all, in fact) on maintaining a semblance of linguistic propriety.  As such it does not fit neatly into formal linguistic categories.

Comment: Another example that works similarly is "mess up" (or screw up, or the other four letter word I originally thought of).  _I messed up_ vs _it messed me up_.  Of course the mess-up or the freak-out can be either internally or externally triggered/generated; I'm not sure why this is concerning to you?

Comment: @HotLicks *Freak* has been around since the sixteenth century, and was used by John Milton. *Etymology: Not found before 16th cent.; possibly introduced from dialects, and cognate with Old English frícian ( Matt. xi. 17) to dance*

Comment: @WS2 - Milton used an [entirely different sense of the word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/freak): *archaic [with object] Fleck or streak randomly:
‘the white pink and the pansy freaked with jet’*.  And the question is not about "freak" but rather "freak out".

Answer (score 7):

You're touching on a number of concepts here: transitive, intransitive; active, passive; grammatical, semantic.

When I heard about the election results,

- Transitive, active:

  > it freaked me out.
- Intransitive, grammatically active:

  > I freaked out.
- Adjective or possibly grammatically passive:

  > I was freaked out.
- Past participle/adjective, semantically passive meaning 'anxious':

  > I felt freaked out.
- Grammatically passive:

  > I was freaked out by the news.

Comment: Can also be used in a nounish sense:  It was a total freak-out.

Comment: I don't disagree with you here. Though I suppose the real problem I'm having concerns what it means to be *freaked-out*. It would appear both to be the result of a force which acts upon you *it freaked me out*, and one that is generated involuntarily from within you *I freaked out*. Some may argue that this is more a question for philosophy, but it is a language issue too.

Comment: @WS2 How is this distinction different from the one of *bewildered*? And probably dozens of other words?

Comment: @AlanCarmack It is not possible to say *She bewildered*, but one can apparently say *She freaked out*. *Freaking-out* seems rare, in that it can both be self-generated (*he freaked out*) and an infliction upon one (*it freaked me out*).

Comment: All right  then look up *ergative* or possibly middle  @WS2. Eg, *She broke*, *it broke her*.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Excellent! Eureka! The answer is that *freak-out* is an example of an ergative verb. (Some languages, Basque and Eskimo, have ergative nouns, where the doer of an action becomes the object) Though a better example might be *He boiled the kettle* - *The kettle boiled*. But if you work your thoughts into  an answer I will both vote for it and accept it as the correct one. This has been a useful team exercise.

Comment: I'm pleased to have been of help, and more so that you've found some assistance; unfortunately I'm not able to write a decent answer at the moment. @WS2

Comment: @WS2 So, whatever the variations in grammar/POS, you're still wondering what the essence of 'freak-out' is? It is that of sudden onset of anxiety. That can be brought about by external circumstances: "I was totally freaked out at the funeral by the appearance of the clown car.", or by internal fears:"I was totally freaking out at the prospect of writing my Oscar acceptance speech for my performance in 'Clown Car at a Funeral' ".

Comment: @WS2 If now your real concern has been elucidated to be "Are there any other words/phrases that act similarly?" I think you'd need to ask a separate question (because changing this one would render the existing answers irrelevant).

Comment: @Mitch That would seem excessively bureaucratic. I did upvote your answer by the way.

Comment: @WS2 No problem. But then I think you got the answer in the comments. There are lots of similar words or really of making such words.

Answer (score 2):

To ***[freak](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/freak_3)*** is both a transitive and intransitive verb, your sentences are an example of its common usages:

(Verb Forms)

> - ***[intransitive, transitive]*** (informal) if somebody freaks or if something freaks them, they react very strongly to something that makes them suddenly feel shocked, surprised, frightened, etc.
> - ***freak (out)*** My parents really freaked when they saw my hair.
> - ***freak somebody (out)***  Snakes really freak me out.

OLD

Comment: I would say the same to you that I have just said to Mitch. The real problem I'm having concerns what it means to be *freaked-out*. It would appear both to be the result of a force which acts upon you *it freaked me out*, and one that is generated involuntarily from within you *I freaked out*. Some may argue that this is more a question for philosophy, but it is a language issue too. Perhaps it is no different to *I worried about it*, and *it worried me*? What do you think?

Comment: @WS2 - when  used as a transitive verb it indicates who/what is freaked-out. The origin the the "freak" is a matter of opinion.